# Install Windows Service using an another Exe file in Non - VS Environment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-services, command-prompt

I have a requirement that i have one Windows service developed in a developer environment. I have to Install my service onto the Windows Server 2008 where i dont have .Net Framework installed. Based on this scenario i chose to go for another EXE file that will install the Windows service.

I have got some normal command prompt can install the Windows service by using this command.

```
c:\> sc create binpath = "my service path [EXE]"
```

But i need to execute this statement in another EXE file. Is there any better solution in this scenario. Kindly help me for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
if (the service is developed with .NET) {
    //do nothing and tell you manager that 
    //.net framework needs to be installed on Windows Server 2008
} else {
    //use the sc command or 
    //put the command in a batch file with conent "sc create binpath = "my service path [EXE]"
}
```